# Send data between two Android devices on same network

Tags: android, sockets

I'm new to android programming and have a question about networking.  I am creating a chess app where two players can play a game against each other on separate devices.  My goal is to set this up so it works locally (the devices are near each other or on the same wifi network).

I noticed when trying to work through WiFi P2P (which thoroughly confused me) that the end goal was to get the MAC filter and IP address of the device you are connecting to.  If I already have these (i.e. the user inputs them on the client device knowing these values externally) can I simply create the connection without using P2P?

In essence, can I simply start a networked android app with creating and connecting to a serversocket rather than dealing with P2P or NSD?

Thanks and sorry for any confusion,
  Scott

Answer (score 0):

you can use the alljyon sdk https://www.alljoyn.org/docs-and-downloads ,i had work with it and it work correctly ,you can find a sample demos one for chat in the same wirless without need the internet connection